How to call an Oracle stored procedure with multiple output parameter- Refcursor and Number example?
I have a problem while calling a stored procedure in Spring JPA using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery. My stored procedure will return multiple parameters, including a REF_CURSOR and a NUMBER (for example, REF_CURSOR is for result set, and number to return total records).
Therefore my code is like this - my entity class:
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Entity
@IdClass(PowerSellDataId.class)
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "PowerSellData.getPowerData",
        procedureName = "PKG_DUBAOTHUONGPHAMCMIS.GET_THUONGPHAM",
        //resultClasses = PowerSellData.class,
        //resultClasses = {PowerSellData.class},
        parameters = {
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_MADVIQLY", type = String.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_THANG", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_NAM", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_LOAIDULIEU", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_SOKY", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_LOAIKH", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_PAGE_NUMBER", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "P_PAGE_SIZE", type = Integer.class),
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "P_RST", type = void.class),
                //@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "P_RST", type = Integer.class),
            @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "P_TOTAL_RECORDS", type = Integer.class)

        })
public class PowerSellData  {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MA_DVIQLY")
    String maDviqly;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MA_KHANG")
    String maKhang;

    @Column(name = "TEN_KHANG")
    String tenKhang;

    @Column(name = "MANHOM_KHANG")
    String maNhomKhang;

    @Column(name = "CSUAT")
    Integer congSuat;

    @Column(name = "THUONG_PHAM")
    Integer thuongPham;

    @Column(name = "ROW_NUM")
    Integer rowNum;
}

My repository class:
package tripqm.evn.java.power.repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.Procedure;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import tripqm.evn.java.power.entity.PowerSellData;

@Repository
public interface PowerRepository extends JpaRepository<PowerSellData, Long> {
    @Procedure(name = "PowerSellData.getPowerData")
    // List<PowerSellData> getPowerData
    Map<String,Object> getPowerData(
            @Param("P_MADVIQLY") String madviqly,
            @Param("P_THANG") int thang,
            @Param("P_NAM") int nam,
            @Param("P_LOAIDULIEU") int loaiDulieu,
            @Param("P_SOKY") int soKy,
            @Param("P_LOAIKH") int loaiKh,
            @Param("P_PAGE_NUMBER") int page,
            @Param("P_PAGE_SIZE") int size);
}

My service class:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
@Slf4j
public class PowerDataService {
    PowerRepository powerRepository;
    PowerDataMapper powerDataMapper;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public PaginationResponse<PowerSellDataResponse> getSellPowerData(
            String madviqly, int thang, int nam, int loaiDulieu, int soKy, int loaiKh, int page, int size) {
        //List<PowerSellData>
        Map<String,Object> sellPowerData = null;
        int totalRecords = 0;
        int totalPages = 0;
        try {
            sellPowerData =
                    powerRepository.getPowerData(madviqly, thang, nam, loaiDulieu, soKy, loaiKh, page, size);
                    //.get("P_RST");
            totalPages = totalRecords / size;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Prints full stack trace
            throw new RuntimeException("Error fetching data from repository: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        List<Object> listPowerData = Arrays.asList(sellPowerData);
//        var result = listPowerData.stream()
//                .map(powerDataMapper::toPowerSellDataResponse)
//                .toList();
        return PaginationResponse.<PowerSellDataResponse>builder()
                .currentPage(page)
                .pageSize(0)
                .totalPages(totalPages)
                .totalElements(totalRecords)
                .data((List)listPowerData)
                .build();
    }
}

I apply exactly like the document on the Spring JPA website: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/stored-procedures.html
Example 7: stored procedure metadata definitions on an entity:
 @Entity
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(name = "User.multiple_out_parameters", procedureName = "multiple_out_parameters", parameters = {
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, name = "arg", type = Integer.class),
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, name = "some_cursor", type = void.class),
      @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.OUT, name = "res", type = Integer.class) })
    public class User {}

Example 8: returning multiple OUT parameters:
@Procedure(name = "User.multiple_out_parameters")
Map<String, Object> returnsMultipleOutParameters(@Param("arg") Integer arg);

But it throws error like this:

org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: Call to stored procedure [PKG_DUBAOTHUONGPHAMCMIS.GET_THUONGPHAM] returned multiple results

Can someone please help me, it will be thankful, because I can't find the answer anywhere on internet.
